# Apple Magic Mouse + IntelliJ IDEA integration

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm using Apple magic mouse + IntelliJ IDEA and I would be happy to map some multi-touches to actions, for instance - go back (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>) etc. Has someone solved this problem?